# Applying Pandas melt() on a dataframe with multiple variable columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. Rows are unique persons and columns are various action types taken. I need the data restructured to show the individual events by row. Here is my current and desired format, as well as the approach I've been trying to implement.

```
current = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'ross', 1: 'allen', 2: 'jon'},'action a': {0:'2017-10-04', 1:'2017-10-04', 2:'2017-10-04'},'action b': {0:'2017-10-05', 1:'2017-10-05', 2:'2017-10-05'},'action c': {0:'2017-10-06', 1:'2017-10-06', 2:'2017-10-06'}})


desired = pd.DataFrame({'name':['ross','ross','ross','allen','allen','allen','jon','jon','jon'],'action':['action a','action b','action c','action a','action b','action c','action a','action b','action c'],'date':['2017-10-04','2017-10-05','2017-10-05','2017-10-04','2017-10-05','2017-10-05','2017-10-04','2017-10-05','2017-10-05']})
```

Comment: `df.melt('name')` if you have pandas v0.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.melt` (v0.20+):

```
df
     action a    action b    action c   name
0  2017-10-04  2017-10-05  2017-10-06   ross
1  2017-10-04  2017-10-05  2017-10-06  allen
2  2017-10-04  2017-10-05  2017-10-06    jon

df = df.melt('name').sort_values('name')
df.columns = ['name', 'action', 'date']
df
    name    action        date
1  allen  action a  2017-10-04
4  allen  action b  2017-10-05
7  allen  action c  2017-10-06
2    jon  action a  2017-10-04
5    jon  action b  2017-10-05
8    jon  action c  2017-10-06
0   ross  action a  2017-10-04
3   ross  action b  2017-10-05
6   ross  action c  2017-10-06
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is the solution I already have working. The top problem is causing me issues.

Comment: @coldspeed introduce a new column to the dataframe and try. I think OP wants a general solution for any number of columns. I will try to comeup with something

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, sorry, I've edited my question to show current and desired data.

Comment: @RossSkinner Okay? That's even simpler than before? Just `df.melt('name')` right?

Answer (score 2):

```
r = df.roles
c = df.roles.str.count(',') + 1
i = df.index
df.loc[i.repeat(c)].assign(roles=','.join(r).split(','))

  company  employer_id                roles
0       a            1             engineer
0       a            1       data_scientist
0       a            1            architect
1       b            2             engineer
1       b            2  front_end_developer
```

Comment: Appreciate the upvote. Unfortunately, we misread OP's question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566832/python-pandas-restructure-dataframe#comment80088201_46566944

Comment: Well, until OP post information that removes ambiguity... It is what it is (-:

Comment: @piRSquared, Thank you for your quick response and help with this thread. I apologize that my initial question was confusing.